# How can I split the neotree window in spacemacs/emacs

Tags: window, neotree

I want my neotree window not to extend all the way to the bottom as shown here.

[image]
How is that possible? If I try to split it I get an error saying the side window can't be split.

Comment: If you provide us with the specific error message, then we won't have to guess as why the window cannot be split ... :)

Comment: @lawlist exact message  says split-window: Cannot split side window or parent of side window

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the full-span shell variable to nil in your dotfile. As in:

```
 (shell :variables
         shell-default-height 30
         shell-default-position 'bottom
         shell-default-full-span nil
         shell-default-shell term)
```

Best, Chris